# Is forbidding template virtual functions an unnecessary cautiousness?

Tags: c++, function, templates, virtual

After reading many posts about similar topics, and thinking about it for a while, still I do not understand why it is forbidden to implement template virtual functions.
The way I see it, this case has nothing to do with mixing static polymorphism with the dynamic one, but it is rather using template differentiation of the functions at the compile-time and then using dynamic polymorphism for each individual created function at the run-time.

Consider this piece of code:

```
class parrent{
public:
    virtual float function(float value)const{
        return value;
    }
    virtual double function(double value)const{
        return value;
    }
    virtual long double function(long double value)const{
        return value;
    }
    virtual ~parrent() = default;
};
class a_child:public parrent{
public:
    float function(float value)const override{
        return value + 1.5;
    }
    double function(double value)const override{
        return value + 1.5;
    }
    long double function(long double value)const override{
        return value + 1.5;
    }
};
```

Obviously this code is OK and will achieve the expected result.
But using template to rewrite a similar code:

```
class parrent{
public:
    template<typename t__>
    virtual t__ function(t__ value)const{
        return value;
    }
    virtual ~parrent() = default;
};
class a_child:public parrent{
public:
    template<typename t__>
    t__ function(t__ value)const override{
        return value + 1.5;
    }
};
```

Is not allowed.

I am not a compiler designer but from what I have read compilers will create a look up table from virtual functions and use them to launch the appropriate function at the run time, which is different from what they do in case of template functions. For any sets of template parameters given to use a template function at the compile time, compiler will create a unique function.
For this example compiler could detect template parameters in compile time simply by looking at how this virtual template function have been used throughout the entire program. Please consider the main function now:

```
int main() {
parrent* a;
parrent* b;
a = new parrent;
b = new a_child;
std::cout<< a->function(1.6f) << std::endl;
std::cout<< a->function(1.6) << std::endl;
std::cout<< a->function(1.6L) << std::endl;
std::cout<< b->function(1.6f) << std::endl;
std::cout<< b->function(1.6) << std::endl;
std::cout<< b->function(1.6L) << std::endl;
delete a;
delete b;
return 0;
}
```

Here Compiler will see that the function was used once for a float value, once for a double value and once for a long double value, so in any case it can easily create the right function with appropriate template parameters.
And in the end there will be 3 individual virtual functionS, not just one virtual function. 
If we have a function which template parameters could not be deduced from the functions inputs like

```
template<typename t__>
virtual t__ function(int value){return value;}
```

Then users can just give the parameters themselves like:

```
object_pointer->function<double>(1234);
```

These practices are just what is already being used in case of any template functions, so why would it be different for virtual functions!

the only caveat to this practice that I can think of would be when the template virtual function get instantiated from a child object and never from the parent object or pointer.
Well even in that case same practice could be applied in order to create different virtual functions. Alternatively due to the lack of use of their virtuality they can become normal individual functions.

From the answer and comments it appears that there might be a serious problem with this approach which is obvious to every one else, so please be patient and help me understand it too.

I guess the mentioned problem in answers has something to do with compiler and/or linker not being able to know how many (and what type of) vtables it should produce for a class with regard to the rest of the codes or different translation units that it might face.

Well lets say it can produce an unfinished vtables list and extend it as it go along. The problem of ending up with two vtables or two different instances of a same class in the of case dynamic linking can already happen with instantiation of a template class with a virtual (non template)function.
So it seems that compilers already have a method to circumvent that problem!

First lets not forget that with regards to c, methods or class non static functions are nothing more than simple functions which require an object as one of their parameters, so lets not think of class as some intricate piece of code.

Second let's not get carried away by how compilers and linkers and what not works today. The language should be standard not the way compilers produce executable! Lets not forget that there are still many features in standard c++ 17 that even GCC does not cover yet!

Please explain to me in term of logic not the way compilers and/or linkers work what is the problem?

Comment: Are you just learning/studying compilers/languages or is there anything you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Consider how many ways this would break dynamic (run-time) linking.  Potentially a `parrent` used in one DLL would not be usable in another because they'd have different vtables.

Comment: "*Please explain to me in term of logic not the way compilers and/or linkers work*" - an important aspect in the C++ standard is implementability. So the logic is that the standard rejects features that are difficult/impossible to implement.

Comment: rustyx, if what you are saying is indeed true for the difficult cases(not the impossible ones), then I guess it is time to move on from C++!

Answer (score 5):

The way compilers implement polymorphic classes is as follows: the compiler looks at the class definition, determines how many vtable entries are needed, and statically assigns one entry in that vtable to each of the class's virtual methods. Wherever one of those virtual methods is called, the compiler generates code that retrieves the vptr from the class and looks up the entry at the statically assigned offset in order to determine the address that needs to be called.

We can now see how having a virtual template would cause issues. Suppose you had a class containing a virtual template. Now, after the end of the class definition, the compiler doesn't know how large to make the vtable. It has to wait until the end of the translation unit, to see the full list of the specializations of the template that are actually called (or to which a pointer-to-member is taken). If the class is only defined in this single translation unit, this problem could be solved by assigning vtable offsets to the template specializations in some increasing order in which they are encountered, then emitting the vtable at the end. However, if the class has external linkage, this breaks down, as when compiling different translation units, the compiler has no way of avoiding conflicts in the assignment of offsets to specializations of the virtual method template. Instead, the vtable offsets would have to be replaced with symbols that would be resolved by the linker once it has seen the list of referenced specializations from all translation units and merged them into a single list. It seems that if standard C++ required virtual templates to be supported, every implementation would have to require the linker to implement this functionality. I can guess that this will not be feasible any time soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think now I can see where the problem could arise. But as you mentioned this is not logically impossible, it is just that the compiler should work harder!  And as to the problem of breaking and merging vtables for different translation units, is it not the similar case if one simply uses a template class with virtual functions (which is allowed) instead of a class with template virtual functions?

Comment: @AKL Class template with virtual functions are quite different; at each point at which the class template is instantiated, the vtable size is known; different translation units may contain vtables for different specializations of the same class template, but this doesn't pose any problems since there is no relationship *between* vtables of different specializations of the same class template.

Comment: @AKL It means that the *linker* has to work harder, which would be a break from a long history of C++ programs being linked using C linkers. Either that, or the compiler would have to use some other mechanism to perform virtual dispatch, and it's not clear what such a mechanism would be, if it needed to be as efficient as the current one.

Comment: Brian what if a class template get instantiated with same template parameters in different translation units? wouldn't that create different vtables for a same class? and if so linker will face a same problem any way! Because again it has to merge those 2 vtables.

Comment: @AKL no, the same vtable would be emitted in each translation unit

Answer (score 1):

I am not a compiler designer but I see a problem with what you are hoping to do.

When you have a virtual template member function, such as

```
template<typename t__>
virtual t__ function(t__ value)const{
    return value;
}
```

there is no end to the types for which that is applicable. How does the compiler know whether to stop at `int` and `double`? There are unlimited number of types for which that function can be instantiated. Would you expect the compiler to generate vtable that takes into account all possible ways that function can be instantiated? That's infinite. It's not doable.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I do not think it would be necessary for the compiler to generate an endless vtable. As I described in my question, first compiler would have to create individual virtual functionS for those types that have been used in the program and are visible in the compile time. Then compiler can create a limited vtable for each individual virtual function.

Comment: @AKL and how does the compiler know all the possible types that are used in your entire program? Keep in mind: The compiler only sees one .cpp file at a time…and generating the code for calling a virtual function requires knowing what the vtable is going to look like…but you can only ever know the complete set of functions that are going to be in your vtable after you have compiled the entire program…see the problem?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think I do not understand your comment completely.  But as it is customary whit each template class or template function, compiler should be able to know where and how this templates have been used in the entire program at the compile time. Am I missing some thing?

Comment: @AKL you're missing the fact that the compiler cannot know where and how every template is used in the entire program before it has finished compiling the entire program…plus the fact that the compiler, in general, never gets to see the entire program because it only compiles individual source files…so the compiler would have to a) always compile the entire program (which it doesn't) and b) always compile the entire program twice, once to build up information on what's going on in the program and another time to actually generate code…

Comment: BTW I do not think this is a vtable problem at all. This is how individual functions are  being made from their templates. The issue of vtableS comes next.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think there are some valid points in your comments. Please write it more comprehensively as an answer so it can be discussed further.

Comment: @AKL the vtable of the base class would have to contain an entry for every instance of the member function template that may potentially be needed. That means whenever you need to know the object layout of the base class, you implicitly need to have information about the entire program at that point. That just absolutely doesn't fit with the way C++ works. Supporting this would require a fundamental change in how the language and toolchains work. And all that for a small feature with questionable practical value…

Comment: @AKL I guess there's no need anymore, the answer by Brian above basically covers all these points.